# How to got to form action after form validation?

Tags: javascript, html, validation, events, event-handling

In my form, I had added a submit event listener which shows the error message on form-group whenever input doesn't satisfy but even after correct submission the login button doesn't redirect me to the action ="/login". Do I have to add additional code in order to work

```
<form id="loginForm" action="/login" method="POST">
                {{#if errorMessage}}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <p class="error">{{errorMessage}}</p>
                </div>
                {{/if}}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <input placeholder="Enter email" name="email" id="loginEmail" type="email">
                    <span id="login-email-error">Message</span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="">Password</label>
                    <input placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" id="loginPassword" type="password">
                    <span id="login-password-error">Message</span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group button">
                    <button id="3" type="submit">Login</button>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group button">
                    <a href="">Forgot Password</a>
                </div>
            </form>
```

```
    form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        checkRequired([loginEmail, loginPwd]);
        checkLength(loginEmail, 3, 34);
        checkLength(loginPwd, 6, 25);
        checkEmail(loginEmail);

    });
```

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` is meant to do just that; prevent the default behavior of the submit button. Part of which is to follow the `action` link. Do you need the `e.preventDefault()`? If so, just do the redirect within your event listener function.

Comment: without event.preventDefault() the form action occurs immediately even when there is errors in the form validation

Answer (score 1):

Redirect to the desired link using

```
window.location = "/your_desired_path";
```

within your `Event Listener` method.

Comment: thanks for answer but this method redirects the user to the path via GET method, but how can we enable the form action="/login" after the validation